# Как создать программу, выполняющую одновременно несколько действий , но при этом не показывающаю все эти действия

Tags: c#, консоль, веб-скрейпинг

Я хочу создать программу-чекер , которая могла бы зайти в аккаунт по логину и паролю и просто дать информацию о нем. При этом нужно чтобы эти процессы не показывались пользователю ради удобства пользования. Как можно такой реализовать? хочу понять как создают подобные программы...
Тоесть в итоге моя программа должна принимать такие данные: логин и пароль, а затем с помощью них заходить в аккаунты и в итоге выводить информацию о нем, но при этом подобное действие должно производиться многократно за 1 раз, т.е. одновременно несколько входов и выводов инфорамации и + не показывать все это на экране пользователя ради удобства.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "Не должны показываться пользователю" - ну так, не показывайте ничего) Ну вот простой метод `public void Test() { var result = 2+2; }` - пользователь увидит что-то? Нет, ну а вот если вы там сделаете еще `Console.WriteLine(result);`, тогда он увидит, да. Так что, ваш вопрос, немного странный. Что касается "несколько за раз" - а это уже может не так воспринять сайт, учтите это. + я надеюсь вы не HTML морду парсите, а работаете с API...? Ну а так, прочитайте про `async/await`, сделаете асинхронную задачу, будет вам фоном что-то делать, ну а увидит или нет - зависит от вас)

Comment: ради удобства))